# Why is x <> 1 false when x is null?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query where a row is selected when `field1 <> 10`.

When `field1` is null, this predicate is `false`!

According to my primitive maths, if `null <> 10 = false`, then `10 = null`.

What is the rational for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression:

```
field1 <> 10
```

doesn't evaluate to `false` when `field1` is `NULL`. It evaluates to `unknown`....which isn't `true`.

See [`IS NULL` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`NULL` and `UNKNOWN` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in the product documentation.

Related reading: [How to Get NULLs Horribly Wrong in SQL Server](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/) by Robert Sheldon

Answer (score 6):

This is because a comparison to `NULL` actually results in unknown. `NULL` is the absence of data and so you are comparing a value against nothing and the result cannot be determined.

> When null values are present in data, logical and comparison operators can potentially return a third result of UNKNOWN instead of just TRUE or FALSE. This need for three-valued logic is a source of many application errors. These tables outline the effect of introducing null comparisons.

Taken from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191504(v=sql.105)) on MSDN.

Comment: Please also specify this is a rdbms method of treating NULL. Other languages like C++ treat it differently.

Comment: @clifton_h the question is tagged as `sql-server` and `t-sql`

Comment: I know. But I just think it is worth understanding since an Application May work differently. Hence the “please”. Not required, but a difference to note.

Comment: also its defined by the SQL standard to be this way.